# VB.NET Delete all bytes after a specific one in a file

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, replace, byte

in my VB.NET program I have to delete all bytes that come after these ones: `48534853` untill it's end (I know that this will corrupt the file).

How can I do that? I already wrote functions to replace a pattern with another one and to locate specific bytes, but I don't know how to wipe out everything after a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`FileStream.SetLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method.

```
Using stream = New FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write)
    fileStream.SetLength(newLength)
End Using
```

--

Try this:

```
Dim pattern As Integer() = New Integer() {&H48, &H53, &H48, &H53}
Dim p As Integer = 0 'Position in pattern.
Using fs = New FileStream("path", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    For pos As Integer = 0 To fs.Length - 1
        Dim b As Integer = fs.ReadByte()
        If b = pattern(p) Then
            p += 1
            If p = pattern.Length Then
                fs.SetLength(pos - pattern.Length + 1)
                Return
            End If
        Else
            p = 0
        End If
    Next
End Using
```

Note that `fs.ReadByte()` returns the byte as `Integer`.

Comment: Thanks, but it's size can change, so I don't always know the exact offset of the pattern. So how can I determinate the file size untill that pattern?

Comment: You are speaking of bytes but show us the number `48534853`. It’s not a byte. Is it a text pattern in a text file? Because accessing characters in a text file is very different from access a steam of bytes. Depending on the encoding, a different number of bytes can be used to represent one character. This must be considered when determining the length in bytes.

Comment: that 'number' are hexadecimal bytes: 48 53 48 53 (in ASCII it's 'HSHS'). I have to find those 8 bytes and delete them + everything after them